# Unity 3DCheck if int is met and do something?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game the player is able to pickup leaves, stones and a wooden log. I want to add conditions to the player that will activate when a certain pickup is equal to 5.

The player consists of 5 modules and each module will be replaced by a pickup when something is picked up. This means the player can consist out of 5 leaves, 5 rocks or 5 wooden logs or a mix of those items.

```
[Header("Real-Time Statistics")]
public int numberOfLeaves;
public int numberOfLogs;
public int numberOfRocks;
```

This aspect is shown in the inspector and gets updated when the player finds a pickup.

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D other){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P)){

            if(other.gameObject.tag == "Leaf"){
                Pickup(1); // 1 = leaf, according to the ModuleStateAndTextureController script.
                numberOfLeaves += 1;
                Destroy(other.gameObject); // destroy the pickup item as we are picking it up
            }
            if(other.gameObject.tag == "WoodLog"){
                Pickup(2); // 2 = wood log, according to the ModuleStateAndTextureController script.
                numberOfLogs += 1;
                Destroy(other.gameObject); // destroy the pickup item as we are picking it up
           }
            if(other.gameObject.tag == "Rock"){
                Pickup(3); // 3 = rock, according to the ModuleStateAndTextureController script.
                numberOfRocks += 1;
                Destroy(other.gameObject); // destroy the pickup item as we are picking it up
            }

        }
    }
```

This part of the script adds a number to the int when a certain pickup is found. I have a similar part within the script when the player drops a pickup.

How would I write a script that checks if a player meets certain conditions, I.e. if the player consists of 5 leaves he would be able to jump higher and descend slower?

What I had in mind was something like: If the player consists out of 5 leaves `jumpPower = 2000;` or something like that. This would be a trait added within the player object I guess, but I also need to know how to use those int on other objects i.e. A trigger that can check if the player consists out of 3 leaves and 2 wooden logs.

I hope someone can help me set this up, because I'm having a hard time scripting as a designer.

Comment: You can add a delegate called when the value of the resources is changed. The delegate would change the value of jumpPower.

Comment: What would something like that look like? I'm not that experienced with coding. I'm currently working on this: 

`void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) {
          if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player" + numberOfRocks >= 5) {
           test.SetActive (true);
          }
         }`
But can't get it to work :(

Comment: I'll give you more details in the next few hours, working right now, or may be someone will answer you before I will.

Comment: I would really appreciate that :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  understood well your need, this is a simple sample of what you could use.
You could use delegates combined with properties to make things happen when the value of a variable is set.

```
public Class MyClass : MonoBehaviour {


    // Delegates, like a pointer in C, but to method(s) instead of variable
        public delegate void valueLogsChangedDelegate (int valueLogs);
        public valueLogsChanged valueLogsChanged = delegate { };


    private int _numberOfLogs;

// Property, when you set numberOfLogs (eg numberOfLogs = 10), every thing in "set" is executed
    public int numberOfLogs {
        get {
            return _numberOflogs;
        }
        set {
            _numberOfLogs = value;
            valueLogsChanged(_numberOflogs);
        }

    }

  /// <summary>
  /// Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded.
  /// </summary>
  void Awake()
  {
      // Subscribe to the delegate, you can add as many methods as you want. Every methods that subscribe to the delegate will be excuted when the delegate is called
      valueLogsChanged += Method;
  }

  void Method(int valueLogs)
  {
      if (valueLogs > 5)
      {
          jumpPower = 2000;
      }
  }

}
```

I am tired so i may have make a mistake. Morover, if I did not understood your need, excuse me!